# Как правильно составить URL?

Tags: python, url, urllib

Пытаюсь составить URL, имея хост и пусть до документа, но ни один из вариантов не выводит ожидаемое `site.com/doc.html`. К хосту нельзя добавлять `/`, он задан в таком формате или с `www`/`https://`. Может надо использовать другую библиотеку?

```
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.urljoin('site.com', 'doc.html'))
print(urllib.parse.urljoin('site.com', '/doc.html'))
print(urllib.parse.urljoin('site.com', 'doc'))
print(urllib.parse.urljoin('site.com', '/doc'))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893374/python-confusions-with-urljoin не ваш случай?

Comment: @Jack_oS там сказано, что надо добавить `/` в хост, чтобы получить нужное поведение